# Emacs ESS Indentation for Scoped R functions

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I currently use emacs ESS and recently agreed to use an internal style guide that uses 2 space indenting. I added the following to my .emacs file:

```
(defun myindent-ess-hook ()
  (setq ess-indent-level 2)
)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'myindent-ess-hook)
```

And everything was going fine.  When I defined a new function, it would nicely indent 2 spaces.  Additionally when I call a function and break the call onto multiple lines, the spacing is also nicely indented with 2 spaces:

```
x <- function(){
  mean(
    c(2,3)
  )      
}
```

However, if I scope the mean function with ::, the indentation gets messed up:

```
x <- function(){
  base::mean(
          c(2,3)
        )
}
```

My guess was that this had something to do with trailing white space, but even after nuking trailing whitespace via:

```
(defun myindent-ess-hook ()
  (setq ess-indent-level 2)
  (setq ess-nuke-trailing-whitespace t)
)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'myindent-ess-hook)
```

The issue persists - has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

My stab in the dark, likely to work for your posted example yet you might dislike the effects in other situations. See `describe-variable` on `ess-offset-arguments-newline` (default value: `prev-call`) for more options, and try:

```
(defun myindent-ess-hook ()
  (setq ess-indent-level 2)
  (setq ess-offset-arguments-newline '(prev-line 2))
)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'myindent-ess-hook)
```

Comment: works for me - and I actually haven't noticed any of the alluded to side-effects.